# how to define 0:00:00 in an IF statement in excel

Tags: excel, date, formula

At E163 cell there is a formula =C163-INT(C164) to get the time, so the result is 0:00:00. If I paste as a value the result is <1900.01.01  0:00:00>
I need to identify 0:00:00 value in an IF statement but Excel doesn't recognize 0 value.
=IF(E163="1900.01.01  0:00:00","midnight")
I also tried

=IF(E163=0,"midnight")

Comment: Excel recognize it as 0. Are you sure you have it "true" zero? Check if it is not really small number behind (like 0.00000015).

Comment: Do you mean `C163-INT(C163)` instead of `C163-INT(C164)`  ? ... check the dates in those cells ..  if different, the result of if function condition will be false

Comment: surpsrisingly the value is 1. you comment drove me to the solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The cell value is 1 not zero. I changed data type from time to number.

Answer (score 0):

why not `=if(E163-INT(E163)=0,"midnight", E163-INT(E163))`

Excel calculates the days as integers and the fraction as the part of the day
for example, day 44201 is midnight  for January, 5th 2021. If we add 0.5 to the number we will get January, 5th 2021 12:00